# Adding multiple .srt subtitle streams to MP4 with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

After a lot of trial and error, I managed to add multiple subtitle streams to one MP4.
However, when checking the metadata of the MP4, I see some results that I want to change, hoping someone can help me or can explain why it happened.

This is the input (original MP4 to which I added subtitle streams)

```
$ ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2048x872 [SAR 1:1 DAR 256:109], 2352 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 440 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Then, I execute the following command. I gathered this information from different sources and I'm not an FFMPEG guru :)

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -f srt -i nl.srt -i mk.srt -i sk.srt \
-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy \
-c:s mov_text -c:s mov_text -c:s mov_text \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=nld -metadata:s:s:1 language=mkd -metadata:s:s:2 language=skv \
NEW.mp4
```

In a few seconds, the NEW.mp4 is created and when playing the video I get the video and audio that I expect and 3 subtitle streams that can be switched during playback. The subtitles itself are also what I expect to be.

Output of NEW.mp4

```
$ ffmpeg -i NEW.mp4 
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2048x872 [SAR 1:1 DAR 256:109], 2352 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 440 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream #0:2(nld): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Stream #0:3(mkd): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Stream #0:4(svk): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

I'm not sure if the type of subtitle is the one I should use -> 'mov_text'. If I use the same command but instead of using 'mov_text', I want to use 'srt' or 'subrip', I get some errors.

```
[mp4 @ 0x7ba2c0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x7ba2c0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x7ba2c0] Could not find tag for codec subrip in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
```

The only question that remains for me is how can I make it work with 'srt' or 'subrip' ? In the meantime I will look for solutions and when found, I will put it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SRTs are not officially supported in MP4s and ffmpeg will not mux them. They have to be converted to the support Timed Text format that you did with `mov_text`.

---

You can get rid of the warning

```
Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
```

by adding `-flags +global_header`.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.. How can I make it work (if possible..) to have subtitles in format _WEBVTT_? If this is even related to FFMPEG :) ...?!

Comment: WebVTT not supported in MP4 by ffmpeg as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the subs to mov_text which is supported for MP4. Like in the command below.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i dutch.srt -i french.srt -i italian.srt -i spanish.srt -i swedish.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 -map 5 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=dut -metadata:s:s:1 language=fre -metadata:s:s:2 language=ita -metadata:s:s:3 language=spa -metadata:s:s:4 language=swe output.mp4
```

Also you have the option to change the container with ffmpeg to use mkv and then you do not need to convert the subs as mkv supports virtually anything.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i dutch.srt -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i french.srt -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i italian.srt -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i spanish.srt -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -i swedish.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 -map 5 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt -metadata:s:s:0 language=dut -metadata:s:s:1 language=fre -metadata:s:s:2 language=ita -metadata:s:s:3 language=spa -metadata:s:s:4 language=swe output.mkv
```

In the cases above I am using the -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 as the srt file is encoded in ISO-8859. You will get the errors like the following if the the srt are not encoded in UTF-8

```
Invalid UTF-8 in decoded subtitles text; maybe missing -sub_charenc option Error while decoding stream #3:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: To preserve metadata from the input file, add `-movflags use_metadata_tags -map_metadata 0` just before the output path [ref](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/24524)

Comment: @ddelange
Im not sure i understand .srt would not have meta data or at least not in my experience.

Comment: ah sorry, I was unclear: the suggestion is to preserve metadata embedded in the input _video_ file